# Reliable Ways to Send Large Files to Clients

Tags: ftp, sftp, transfer

we have a need to regularly provide large files to clients on a daily or weekly basis.  Currently our process is this:

- Internal process creates the file and places it in a specific folder
- Our client connects via SFTP and downloads the file

This work well when the files are small.  As they get bigger (50-100 GB in size), we keep getting network interruptions and internal disk space related issues.

What I'd like to see is the following:

- Our internal process creates the file.
- This file is copied to an intermediary service (similar to something like FileDropper).
- Our client will download the file from this intermediary service.

I'd like to know if other people had similar issues and what possible solutions are in place.  File Dropper works great for non-business related files but obviously I won't be putting client data on there.  We also have an Office 365 subscription.  I tried to see what I could use with that but I haven't found anything yet that would help solve this.

Any hints, suggestions or feedback is much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).
I have used it several times in the past and it is very reliable both for processing a lot of files and for processing large files